# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec does not open swing application in foreground

Tags: java, swing, runtime.exec

I have a Java Swing application, which when a button is clicked, it should launch an external Swing application. I use Java the following to launch this app.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C swingtest.exe")
```

I can see that the `swingtext.exe` is running in the task manager, but the GUI which should pop up (`JFrame` which I've set to visible, 'always on top', 'to front') does not get displayed at all. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: why not add the external application as a dependency and call it like that?

Comment: The whole reason why we want to implement it like this, is to eliminate dependencies, as we also need to be able to run both apps independently on separate machines.

Comment: Simply run it as `<MyMainClass>.main(new String[0]);`

Comment: @Kirsten on seperate machines... how much control do you have over these machines?
also: what happens if you run the swingtest.exe on it's own?

Comment: Sergiy, we do not want to call the external app as a dependency. 
@Stultuske, swingtest.exe's is completely capable of running as a standalone exe. There are certain conditions in the main class of swingtest.exe that will handle logic.

Comment: just the fact that you are running exe files .... you should be looking at another programming language

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: Why are you using `cmd /c`?

Comment: I'm using cmd /c as it need to run as an elevated process. @AndrewThompson, I have looked at that link previously, also tried using ProcessBuilder, but it gives the same result.

Comment: But `cmd /c` by itself doesn't run with elevated privileges. Did you mean `cmd /c runas /user:admin swingtest.exe`?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException It does complain about elevation if I do not include the cmd /c